# Zeppelin 0.7.3 got local class incompatible error

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I simply installed Spark 2.2.1 standalone cluster and zeppelin 0.7.3. I tried some logistic regression code like below:

```
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10000, regParam=0.2)
model1 = lr.fit(training)
trainingSummary = model1.summary
objectiveHistory = trainingSummary.objectiveHistory
for objective in objectiveHistory:
    print(objective)
trainingSummary.roc.show()
print("areaUnderROC(training): " + str(trainingSummary.areaUnderROC))

prediction = model1.transform(test)
prediction_train = model1.transform(training)

evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator().setLabelCol("label").setRawPredictionCol("probability").setMetricName("areaUnderROC")
pred_test=prediction.select("label","probability","rawPrediction")
pred_train=prediction_train.select("label","probability","rawPrediction")

ROC_test=evaluator.evaluate(pred_test)
ROC_train=evaluator.evaluate(pred_train)


print("areaUnderROC(training): " + str(ROC_train))

print("areaUnderROC(testing): " + str(ROC_test))
```

and got the following error. googled and found such problem was fixed in 0.7.1 when reading JSON.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, 192.168.0.17, executor 0): java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateParser; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2, local class serialVersionUID = 3
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:687)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at
```

....

```
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: 
    org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateParser; local class incompatible: 
    stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2, local class serialVersionUID = 3
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:687)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
....
```